# default value of a variable at the time of declaration in PL SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

What is the default value of a variable `VARCHAR2` at the time of declaration in PL/SQL? Can I check it against `NULL` once after I declare a variable?

Answer (score 24):

Variables are default initialized with NULL.

You can change that, for example:

```
create procedure show1
as
  l_start varchar2(10) := 'Hello';
begin
  if l_start is not null then 
    ....
  end if;
end;
/
```

You can also declare variables as not nullable:

```
create procedure show2
as
  l_start varchar2(10) not null := 'Hello';
begin
  null;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 2):

Defaults are NULL, you can use IS NULL or IS NOT NULL.

Answer (score 1):

And another small addition: if you're dealing with BLOBs (or CLOBS), "empty" is not the same as null. See the Oracle large objects manual if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

tuinstoel is correct.

One addition: Don't be fooled into trying "ls_my_variable = NULL" as comparing with NULL always returns FALSE. Always use "ls_my_variable IS NULL" or "IS NOT NULL".